# PHP Create timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I am beginner in php programming. I am Trying to compare 2 Timestamp type which are saved in database,
here is my Code:

```
$sdate = "{$_POST['sdatey']}-{$_POST['sdatem']}-{$_POST['sdated']} $stime";
$edate = "{$_POST['edatey']}-{$_POST['edatem']}-{$_POST['edated']} $etime";
$startdate = strtotime($sdate);
$enddate = strtotime($edate);
$diff = floor($enddate - $startdate);

if($diff > 0){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `leave` (TypeID, StatusID, StaffID, StartDate, EndDate, CreateDate) VALUES ('1','1', {$_SESSION['user']['ID']} , '$sdate', '$edate', '$date')";
header('Location:ApplyLeave-Step3.php');
}
else {
echo "wrong";       
}
```

Comment: where are you comparing ? what is $date2 $date1. What is the issue ?

Comment: Always the result for if is correct, it never goes to Else Statement,

Comment: what is the value of $date2, $date1

Comment: I am not sure about the first line, Is the formatting correct to create the the Timestamp?

Comment: Give us some sample **values** you're working with.

Comment: @deceze this is the example when I insert the time inside my code:          $startdate = "2007-03-24 00:00:00";
    $enddate = "2004-06-26 00:00:00";

Comment: @deceze when I insert the value inside the programm it works correctly, but when I want to get it from input, have wrong result,

Comment: Then obviously there's a problem in transferring the values via POST, not in the rest of the algorithm. Give us the values you're receiving. `var_dump($_POST);` to debug.

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: @deceze This is how I Post the time value Is it correct:    <select  class="styledselect_form_1" name="Stime">
                                                                    <option value="09:00:00" name="9">9:00 AM</option>

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($sdate));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($edate));
//I have changed the startdate and enddate because you want to insert it into DB
$diff = abs(strtotime($enddate ) - strtotime($startdate));

$sql = "INSERT INTO `leave` 
    (TypeID, StatusID, StaffID, StartDate, EndDate, CreateDate) 
    VALUES 
    ('1','1','".$_SESSION['user']['ID']."', '$startdate', '$enddate', '$date')"; 
    //$date: I cannot see it is anywhere initialized.
```

Comment: I try your code ,but when I echo the value for $diff show me this number 299199600 ! and still never goes to else statement,

Comment: It will go to else part only when both the datetime are exactly equal. I've used `abs` bcoz u have used `$diff > 0` so there is only one condition when it goes to else is both of them should be exactly equal.

Comment: But when both datetime are equal also it does not goes to the else statement.I need to check if enddate is greater than startdate . How can I do that?